# Why my combobox is null? even though not beeing null

Tags: c#, combobox

I am using c1 combobox from another class, but value is null but actually not. Default value is "8".
It is working on Form1 class properly I can see values that I picked, but Form2

*Form1.cs*

```
c1.Items.Add(8);
```

*Form1.Designer.cs*

```
 public static System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox c1;
```

*Form2.cs class*

```
 MessageBox.Show(Form1.c1.Text);
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `static` control on a form.

Comment: *"but value is null but actually not"* - It can't simultaneously be both.  So which is it?  What specifically is the problem?  Where do you ever set a value to `c1`?  Is the code in `Form2` running before or after you set that value?  Why is `c1` set as `static` in the first place?

Comment: Form2 actually should have no idea that Form1 even _has_ a combobox. They should share a model class instance.

Comment: I set the value with property of the combobox I referred that when I say "actually not"
variable has value if I use in Form1. but when It comes to Form2 value is null @David
I define as a static because if I do not that all values comes through null into Form2

Comment: How can I do that @Fildor

Comment: I am a junior developer just tell me why @GSerg

Comment: @sarac: Nowhere in the code shown is a value ever being set to `c1`.  And semantically it really makes no sense for a `ComboBox` to be `static`.  Maybe it would make more sense if you just have a *value* be `static` and set that value whenever the user changes something.  We don't really know what you're trying to do, so all we can do is guess.  But you're going to need to provide more of an example of the problem, your description is entirely unclear and the code shown doesn't demonstrate anything.

Comment: That would be overkill in an answer. You might want to invesitigate "Winforms MVC" or "Winforms MVVM" on how to work with model-driven patterns in winforms.

Comment: I edited my topic could you check this out @David

Comment: @sarac: You're adding an element to the `Items` array, but does that update the `Text` property to anything?  It might in a regular form control based on built-in UI logic (I'm not sure), but does that logic happen for a `static` instance?  It still doesn't make sense to have a `static` form control, so who knows.  The core of the issue appears to be that, whatever you're trying to do, you're going about it the wrong way.  This is called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to set the value is actually executed in `Form1`'s context only. Since you made it a static field without understanding what you are doing that initialization code does not get a chance to execute and code in `Form2` happily sees the null value.

So says my psychic debugging about this ill-defined problem statement.